# Should the suspended coroutine handle be always destroyed before program ends?

Tags: c++, destructor, c++20, coroutine

Look at this simplified example:

```
std::coroutine_handle<> logger;
const char* next_msg = nullptr;
void log(const char* msg)
{
    next_msg = msg;
    if (logger) logger.resume();
}

struct wait_msg {
    bool await_ready() {
        return next_msg != nullptr;
    }
    void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h) {
        logger = h;
    }
    auto await_resume() {
        const char* msg = next_msg;
        next_msg = nullptr;
        return msg;
    }
};

struct procedure {
    struct promise_type;
    using handle_type = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;
    
    handle_type handle;

    struct promise_type {
        procedure get_return_object() { 
            return { handle_type::from_promise(*this)};
        }
        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        void return_void() {}
        void unhandled_exception() { std::terminate(); }
    };
};

procedure log_messages()
{
    int c = 1;
    for (;;) {
        const char* msg = co_await wait_msg{};
        std::cout << c++ << ": " << msg << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Assuming I have no suspension at initial or final points and coroutine is suspended on co_await, should the coroutine handle be destroyed before the program ends?

Or: can line `p.handle.destroy();` be removed from `main`?

```
int main() {
    log("Hello World!");

    auto p = log_messages();
    
    log("Hello World, again!");
    log("Hello World, and again!");
    
    // is the next line needed?
    p.handle.destroy();
}
```

See full [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fYr8neq76).

Previous version of code in question [here](https://godbolt.org/z/exefY4a88).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should the suspended coroutine handle be always destroyed before program ends?

**No**, there are cases when `destroy()` is not needed nor even possible.

**Yes**, in the code from question, `destroy()` on coroutine handle is needed.

This quote from the [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine) explains the thing:

> The coroutine state is destroyed when control flows off the end of the
> coroutine or the destroy member function
> ([coroutine.handle.resumption]) of a coroutine handle
> ([coroutine.handle]) that refers to the coroutine is invoked.

Since this coroutine never go out of infinite loop (`for(;;)`) - it has to be destroyed via its handle.

```
procedure log_messages()
{
    int c = 1;
    for (;;) {
        const char* msg = co_await wait_msg{};
        std::cout << c++ << ": " << msg << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However, the code could be slightly modified - like - returns nullptr when there is no more lines to print, and breaks the loop on nullptr:

```
procedure log_messages()
{
    int c = 1;
    for (;;) {
        const char* msg = co_await wait_msg{};
        if (!msg) break; // !!!
        std::cout << c++ << ": " << msg << std::endl;
    }
}
```

In that case - destroy() is not needed nor even possible, as it would cause UB.
It is because `destroy()` can only be called on suspended coroutine, and we have no suspensions in final point in the code in question:

```
    struct promise_type {
        //...
        std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        //...
    };
};
```